# how to INSERT updated records into another table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I was answered by @Dharman for my problem (plz click here-> **[How to update stock quantity according to their batch numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246809/how-to-update-stock-quantity-according-to-their-batch-numbers)**. And his suggested code is working for me.

**Now, I just want to INSERT the updated rows into "temp_sales".**
Here is sample picture of required "temp_sales" https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1an.png.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to copy data from one table to another? But anyway...investigate `INSERT...SELECT` queries

Comment: Actually I want to keep track of profits on same product which was purchased on different prices (according to their batch numbers) and sold on same price. i.e I purchased 1 Coke bottle at pur_price of 5,6,7 or 8 and sale price was 10. How can I keep track of profits?

Comment: Well don't you already keep a record of what price you purchased things at?

Comment: Surely yes, but using no good method. But this time I am working to keep track of inventory by their batch numbers because it will help me to calculate batch-wise profits of each product.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the trigger like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_updated_data BEFORE UPDATE ON temp_sales
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO temp_sales2 (product_code, batch_number, qty, pur_price, price) VALUES (new.product_code, new.batch_number, new.qty, new.pur_price, new.price);
END
```

Enjoy... :)

Comment: hello wiwek jannat on using your suggested trigger I am getting the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Can you please give me the trigger SQL code that you have been used for that?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER insert_updated_data
BEFORE UPDATE ON purchase_order
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `employees_audit`
SET
action = new.batch_number,
employeeNumber = new.unitPrice, 
lastname = new.qty_avbl,
changedat = new.salePrice
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: You don't need to use SET keyword in insert query. Your query is wrong man.
Try this:
INSERT INTO employees_audit (action,employeeNumber,lastname,changedat) VALUES (new.batch_number, new.unitPrice, new.qty_avbl, new.salePrice);

Comment: Its working now. thanks @wiwek jannat